# Can I make a widget visible when button is pressed?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is there any way for displaying a widget when a button is clicked ? But **not** as a pop up with `template = true` and `slotId = cockpitWidgetChildrenInvisible` like in this example :

```
<widget-extension widgetId="mainSlot">
    <widget id="paragraphsPopup" widgetDefinitionId="com.training.backoffice.widgets.paragraphspopup"
            slotId="cockpitWidgetChildrenInvisible" template="true">
        <setting key="_width" type="String">500px</setting>
        <setting key="_height" type="String">auto</setting>
        <instance-settings>
            // instance settings here for close / init / select.
        </instance-settings>
        <virtual-sockets/>
    </widget>
</widget-extension>
```

I want the widget to be invisible in a Default Portal Widget maybe in the `children` slot and when I press a button the widget becomes visible. (Again : **NOT** as a pop-up widget)

Comment: What is the widget you are trying to show? Is it assigned to a slotId? Is it a custom widget?

Comment: Is just a simple widget placed in defaultPortalWidget in the `children` slotId. But I want to show it only on a pressed button event. I was thinking that maybe there is a method like `widget.setVisible(false)` and the event listener will eventually modify it to `widget.setVisible(true)` .